# Thread-safe cache using a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, thread-safety, cache, c++17

Are the final templated functions `allocate` and `deallocate` thread safe? The `Cache` object is a `thread_local` and that also makes `FreeList` a `thread_local`, the only parts that I'm still in doubt are the calls to `std::malloc` and `std::free`. Are they always thread safe or that depends on the implementation? Is it better to put a lock on them?

I think that the cached memory doesn't need locks since all the objects here are `thread_local` and each thread has a local copy of it. The only problem really are `std::malloc` and `std::free`, are they already synchronized?

Here's a self contained example of all of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class FreeList {
    struct Node {
        Node * next;
    };

    Node * this_head;

public:
    static constexpr auto const NODE_SIZE = sizeof(Node);

    FreeList() noexcept
        : this_head() {
    }

    FreeList(FreeList &&) = delete;
    FreeList(FreeList const &) = delete;

    FreeList & operator =(FreeList &&) = delete;
    FreeList & operator =(FreeList const &) = delete;

    void push(void * const address) noexcept {
        auto const head = static_cast<Node *>(address);
        head->next = this_head;
        this_head = head;
    }

    auto pop() noexcept {
        void * const head = this_head;
        if (head) {
            this_head = this_head->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
};

template <uint64_t const SIZE>
class Cache {
    static_assert(SIZE >= FreeList::NODE_SIZE);

    FreeList this_free_list;

public:
    Cache() noexcept
        : this_free_list() {
    }

    Cache(Cache &&) = delete;
    Cache(Cache const &) = delete;

    ~Cache() noexcept {
        while (auto const address = this_free_list.pop()) {
            // Do I need a lock here?
            std::free(address);
        }
    }

    Cache & operator =(Cache &&) = delete;
    Cache & operator =(Cache const &) = delete;

    auto allocate() {
        if (auto const address = this_free_list.pop()) {
            return address;
        }
        // Do I need a lock here?
        if (auto const address = std::malloc(SIZE)) {
            return address;
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    void deallocate(void * const address) noexcept {
        if (address) {
            this_free_list.push(address);
        }
    }
};

template <typename TYPE>
auto & get() noexcept {
    thread_local TYPE local;
    return local;
}

template <typename TYPE>
auto & get_cache() noexcept {
    return get<Cache<sizeof(TYPE)>>();
}

// Are these thread safe?

template <typename TYPE>
auto allocate() {
    auto const address = get_cache<TYPE>().allocate();
    return static_cast<TYPE *>(address);
}

template <typename TYPE>
void deallocate(void * const address) noexcept {
    get_cache<TYPE>().deallocate(address);
}

int main() {

    auto x = allocate<int64_t>();

    *x = 5;

    std::cout << *x << '\n';

    deallocate<int64_t>(x);

}
```

Comment: Which C++ version is this targeting? C++11? C++14? C++17?

Comment: I'm targeting mainly C++17, but the more versions, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the final templated functions `allocate` and `deallocate` thread safe?

As every other state used is thread-local, the answer hinges on this:
Is the `malloc()`/`free()` memory-management-system thread-safe?

The C++ Standard just defers to the C standard:

> [*Effects: These functions have the semantics specified in the C standard library.*](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#lib:malloc)

And the C Standard says something like (from C11 final draft n1570):

> 2. For purposes of determining the existence of a data race, memory allocation functions behave as though they accessed only memory locations accessible through their arguments and not other static duration storage. These functions may, however, visibly modify the storage that they allocate or deallocate. A call to `free` or `realloc` that deallocates a region *p* of memory synchronizes with any allocation call that allocates all or part of the region *p*. This synchronization occurs after any access of *p* by the deallocating function, and before any such access by the allocating function.

So, in the end, the answer is:
**Yes**, it's thread-safe.

---

Now, let's critic your code:

1. You are only using `FreeList` for `Cache`, and don't call any of its methods more than once.
   Abstraction and encapsulation are tools for managing complexity, but all that useless boilerplate increases it instead.
2. There is no valid reason `Cache` and `FreeList` aren't literal types, which don't depend on dynamic initialization.
   Use `constexpr`, or better yet move to an in-class-initializer and `=default` the default-ctor.
3. To make a type non-copy- and non-move- constructible and assignable, it suffices to declare an explicitly deleted move-ctor or move-assignment-operator.
4. While it's a good thing ``` Cache``static_assert ```s the block-size is big enough, make `get_cache()` fix the request if needed. The caller should not have to care.
5. Consider writing an [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) using your caching-system. That way, it can be used by standard containers, instead of just manually. Though admittedly, as the block-size is a compile-time-constant, it can only be used in containers allocating single nodes instead of whole arrays.

Comment: So, does that mean that I can use my `allocate` and `deallocate` functions fiercely without having to worry about data races?

Comment: Yes, it's thread-safe. Whether it's a good idea depends on your use-profile. And changing to use the interface an Allocator should provide is also recommended, so you can use it for standard containers.

Comment: `std::malloc` and `std::free` are thread-safe, the rest isn't.

Comment: @hoffmale: If you look at the code, `std::malloc()` and `std::free()` are the only places where shared data-structures are used. Everything else is `thread_local` (whether directly or indirectly), and thus already thread-safe.

Comment: @Deduplicator: `get` isn't the only way to instantiate a `Cache`, since the constructor is `public`.

Comment: @hoffmale, we're just looking at the final functions here, it's normal that they're unsafe in the middle. What's matters is that the final two functions are safe to use. That's why there's `get` and `get_cache`, that's the API I pretend.

Comment: @JoãoPires: The problem is that the "unsafe middle" is `public`ly accessible. If I want a non-static `Cache`, I can simply create one - and that one isn't thread-safe (other than the constructor and destructor).

Comment: @hoffmale that was just a self contained example, in my code everthing is sorted into namespaces. Both the `FreeList` and the `Cache` are in a `Private` namespace.

Comment: @hoffmale Sorry, but if you follow that logic, just about nothing is thread-safe, because it's built out of non-thread-safe building-blocks, most of which are publicly available.

Comment: @JoãoPires: That's some context not obvious from the question. // @Deduplicator: My problem is that a blanket statement "this is thread-safe" doesn't hold if there are non-thread-safe access paths. This doesn't mean building blocks all have to be thread-safe, just that the non-thread-safe parts must not  be `public`ly accessible and have to be properly regulated. (Like having the safest door doesn't make a house burglar-proof if the ground-level windows are wide open.)

Answer (score 5):

## Thread safety

`std::malloc` and `std::free` are thread-safe by themselves... But `Freelist` and `Cache` **aren't**, unless exclusively accessed through `allocate` or `deallocate`.

In all other cases some synchronization is needed in `FreeList::push` and `FreeList::pop` (or alternatively, `Cache::allocate` and `Cache::deallocate`).

> There are some options to make those two classes thread-safe for all access paths:
>
> 1. Move `get`, `get_cache`, `Cache` and `FreeList` into a `class` as `private` nested classes / member functions (so they aren't publicly accessible anymore) and make `allocate` and `deallocate` a `friend` of that class. (private/anonymous `namespace` won't work since that one has to ve just as accessible as `allocate`/`deallocate` because it has to reside in a header.)
>
>    Why move `get` and `get_cache`? Because references and pointers to `thread_local` objects can be shared with other threads - so a threads might get access to another threads `thread_local Cache` inside `get`.
>
>    `thread_local` objects are only thread-safe if no reference or pointer to them gets shared with other threads (which might happen accidentally, e.g. by a mismanaged lambda capture).
>
>    This means `allocate` and `deallocate` are not thread-safe as long as references to the underlying `Cache` (via `get` or `get_cache`) could be shared by someone else. And since `allocate` and `deallocate` have exactly the same level of access as `get` or `get_cache` the posted implementation is not thread-safe in the general case.
> 2. Add some locking inside `FreeList`, or make `FreeList` lock-free by making `this_head` a `std::atomic<Node*>`.
>
>    This would make the critical section inside `Cache::allocate` and `Cache::deallocate` thread-safe as well.

## Memory management

- `Cache::allocate` won't provide correctly aligned memory for alignments greater than `std::max_align_t` (`std::malloc` is only specified to support alignments to this value). This might cause problems if higher alignments are needed, e.g. for SSE or AVX instructions.

  `std::aligned_alloc` could be used as a replacement. (Beware: `std::aligned_alloc` isn't available for MSVC yet.)
- It isn't possible to create objects whose size is less than `sizeof(void*)` - so exchanging `int64_t` for `int32_t` inside `main` will fail to compile on 64-bit systems. This could be fixed by always allocating chunks of memory that are at least `sizeof(void*)` (or `FreeList::NODE_SIZE`, if you prefer).

## Naming

- `Cache` doesn't actually cache objects - only chunks of memory. `FreeListAllocator` might be a better name.
- `get` is a very generic name. (`get_`)`thread_local_instance` or `singleton` might be more descriptive.
- Similar, `get_cache` might better be `get_allocator` or `get_thread_local_allocator`.

## General stuff

- With some slight modifications `Cache` could be changed into a standard library compatible `std::pmr::memory_resource` - which would allow it to be used with standard containers.
- If I had to design this, I'd likely make `FreeList` an adaptor over another allocator (taken as template parameter) who would be asked for memory if the list was empty. This design would allow easy composition of different allocation strategies. There's an [excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) by Andrei Alexandrescu about this topic.

Comment: Adding synchronisation to code which is never used with data shared across threads is quite wasteful.

Comment: @Deduplicator: "never used with data shared across threads" is not a quality that OP's implementation provides. `get` returns a reference to a `thread_local` object - but that reference can be passed to other threads, which then would still reference the original object. As long as `get` and `get_cache` are as accessible as `allocate` and `deallocate` none of those functions are thread-safe. So to make it thread-safe either the access via `get`/`get_cache` needs to be made `private` or the critical operations (at least `FreeList::push`/`FreeList::pop`) need to be synchronized.

Comment: Just using `thread_local` doesn't mean "inaccessible from other threads". Yes, using the corresponding name refers to a different instance on each thread, but pointers or references to those instances can still be shared.

Comment: It's about as good as it reasonably gets (meaning without encumbering usability, maintainability, or efficiency unreasonably), but C++ isn't really designed to enforce such things. If the user wants, he can circumvent any obstacle, reasonable or not.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't think it's an obstacle if the "circumvention" is as simple as passing the result from `get_cache` to a function or lambda which in turn then gets called by a thread pool. The caller gets a reference, passes a reference, and suddenly he has data races - by only using an API that your answer advertised as thread-safe.

Comment: That again. Those internal functions are defined to give access to a unique instance for the local thread. Yes, you can pass the reference to another thread, but that's obviously not allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80625/discussion-between-hoffmale-and-deduplicator).